# database design performance issue asking for advice

Tags: database, performance, geo

I am designing a database to store geo-position. I want to implement similar function to Google Map. The usage scenario is, I have a large number of points, and related X, Y position. The database is seldom update (e.g. adding new points or modify X,Y position for existing points), but query frequently. The query scenario is, for a given square (the square's 4 corner points X,Y positions are known), find all points and related X,Y positions in the square.

I am wondering how to design database so that query performance is optimized. My design issue is very similar to map database design. I am also wondering whether Google Map or traditional map database is implemented to achieve the best performance?

I am new to the area of map database design, appreciate if anyone could refer some tutorials for newbie.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George,
you'll find your positions with

```
where (geoX between %x1 and %x2) and (geoY between %Y1 and %y2)
```

Regarding indexing, since you probably always will query for both X and Y a single index will do:
    idx_XY (geoX, geoY)

If any need to search on just Y, add second index

```
idx_Y (geoY)
```

(And I'd rename X / Y to long/lat, but that's more or less a personal matter, ;-)

regards,
/t

Comment: Thanks @user247245! For the query you posted, why it will use index on (X, Y)? My confusion is I think (geoX between %x1 and %x2) will use index X, and (geoY between %Y1 and %y2) will use index Y. So, should I create index on X and index on Y? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: A composite index (X,Y) will filter faster. If built as (x,Y) the DBMS will search the X first, then Y, just as lastname, firstname in a old-time phone-bible. The Y-index is only needed when only requesting Y-ranges, since then, the X,Y-index won't work. Think of it as you can't easily find all "Sandra" in a phonebook, You'd need another "register" for that. regards //t

Answer (score 1):

Are you tied to some existing database backend? Some databases (like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) and [PostgreSQL](http://postgis.refractions.net/)) have this feature already built in.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I can not use the existing DB you mentioned. For the legacy system reason, I have to design from scratch by myself. I am based on SQL Server or Oracle database (legacy application is using mixed database system). So, I want to learn the ideas about how MongoDB Or PostgreSQL implements map database, then I can use the similar idea (maybe simpler than them) in my legacy application. Do you have any recommended tutorials about how to design map database?

Comment: In its simplest implementation, if you don't need to know distances between points or to worry about a true circular radius search, then it's simply a bounds check like "select * from table where lat > x1 and lat < x2 and lon > y1 and lon < y2;"

Comment: Should I create index on x and y columns? If yes, how to create the index (e.g. create one index on x, the other on y; or create index on x,y two columns) so that the index is used to speed up query for the 4 conditions you mentioned above? Appreciate if you could refer some tutorials about the general ideas of how to design GIS database, so that I can learn more background before design and implementation.

Comment: Well I think you've basically got five options regarding indexing: x, y, x and y, x+y, y+x, x+y and y+x. I would guess that either (x and y) or (x+y and y+x) is best but don't rely on my guess -- benchmark each with your actual data and see what you get. Regarding tutorials, I have none bookmarked or otherwise handy so I'd just suggest googling it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, why do you think index on (x and y) or (x+y and y+x) is best? I want to learn how do you make this conclusion.

Comment: It gives the query optimizer more choices -- although... that can sometimes be a bad thing, so really, the only way to be sure is to test it directly.

Comment: Thanks Alex, from below @user247245's reply and my comment, I think only index on X and index on Y will be used. Why index on X+Y will be used?